# For loop for enemy respawn

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

working on an enemy respawn function in a game however my for loop seems to have no effect as I still only have one ememy moving across the screen, thanks

```
Monster.prototype.draw = function () {      
        for (var i=0; i <5; i++){
        clearMonster();
        monsterCon.drawImage(sprite, this.locationX, this.locationY, this.width, this.height, this.destinationX, this.destinationY, this.width, this.height);
                    this.checkKeys();
        }
    };
```

Comment: `clearMonster();` aren't erasing your monster?

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing your monster on each iteration of your loop prior to adding it again.

Comment: The clearMonster() function just ensures that the canvas is redrawn each time so that the monster does not leave a trail on itself

Comment: Move the function call outside of the loop? You seem to be erasing the four last painted monsters on the fifth loop run, before painting the fifth and only monster.

Comment: @user2317489 The ***whole*** canvas is erased before ***each*** monster is drawn? There you have the reason why you see only one.